# sympy - module 'sympy' has no attribute 'symbols'

Tags: python, sympy

I am studying the sympy package with Python 3.7, but not even the simplest code does compile. Here is my entire code:

```py
import sympy as sy

x = sy.symbols('x')
sy.expand((x+1)**3)
```

and the error message I get is

```py
AttributeError: module 'sympy' has no attribute 'symbols'
```

What can I do?

Comment: This works as-is on python 3, maybe you are on python 2 (unsure if there is a difference)? Maybe you could relaunch your interpreter? Maybe you have tabs mixed with space?

Comment: I am using Phyton 3.7 on the _Spyder_ environment

Comment: this is not a problem with sympy. Do you have a python file named sympy.py in the same working directory maybe?

Comment: Yup, just changed the name and now it works. Thank you very much @ParitoshSingh